# PHP User-statistic Software

Tags: php, statistics

I'm looking for a good PHP User-statistic Software, all I can find are outdated (I have to add things like Win8 manually) or have not enough Informations. 
I want the know things like: normal time Statistic, Country, Language, Bots, Refer, Seen Pages, etc.

Hope someone can give me a tip.

Comment: Most people have taken this to Google analytics, that's why you won't find much out there on the PHP side. Hard to compete.

Comment: I don't want a external Service, because of AddBlocker etc I think they can be blocked and then I want the data on my Webspace. I thought about Google analytics. But I would prefer a local solution.

Comment: you want some log analysis tool? Like awstats or [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/awstats/)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

- http://www.haveamint.com/ - not free
- http://piwik.org/ - free